# problems in installing mylyn mantis connector to eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, mylyn, mantis

I am having problems on installing mantis-mylyn connector to eclipse luna. I am getting the following error.

> Missing requirement: Mylyn Mantis Connector Core 3.10.0.201311082300
>   (com.itsolut.mantis.core 3.10.0.201311082300) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.soap [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be
>   found

in previous versions of eclipse (kepler ...) the plugin was working without any problems. But I don't want to return to kepler, because luna is better. In kepler, I had the problem of freezing of editors, which was slowing me down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mylyn removed the SOAP bundle from their update site, see [Eclipse bug#421379: remove SOAP transport from Mylyn](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421379). Until an official update is out, I suggest that you do the following:

- Add the following update site to Eclipse: http://archive.eclipse.org/mylyn/drops/3.10.0/v20131025-2037, without installing anything from it
- Try to install the MantisBT connector again, and make sure to enable 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software'